Active session for the last server in the list, instead that one that i click
I have created a PowerShell script that displays a list of servers on a Windows form. If a server has more than 2 active users, the button turns red, indicating the server is busy. If there are fewer than 2 active users, the server is available and the button turns green. When I click on a server, the script should initiate an RDP session for the selected server.
The issue is that, when I click on any server, the script always opens the RDP session for the last server in the list (in this case, server3), regardless of which server I select.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$servers = @("server1", "server2", "server3")
$credentials = Get-Credential

function Get-ServerStatus {
    param ($server, [PSCredential]$credentials)
      try {
        $sessionInfo = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential               $credentials -ScriptBlock {
            query user /server:$env:COMPUTERNAME
        } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $activeSessions = ($sessionInfo | Where-Object { $_ -match "Active" }).Count
        return $activeSessions
    } catch {
    return -1
    }
}

function Start-RDP {
    param ($server, [PSCredential]$credentials)
    cmdkey /generic:"$server" /user:"$($credentials.UserName)"    /pass:"$($credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password)"
    Start-Process "mstsc.exe" "/v:$server /f"
}

# New Window form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Server Status"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300, 400)

# Title
$titleLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$titleLabel.Text = "Stato dei server:"
$titleLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280, 30)
$titleLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$titleLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16,     [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$titleLabel.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter
$form.Controls.Add($titleLabel)

$y = 60
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $status = Get-ServerStatus -server $server -credentials $credentials
    $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260, 30)
    $button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, $y)
    $y += 40

    if ($status -eq -1) {
        $button.Text = "$server not accessible"
        $button.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Red
    } elseif ($status -gt 2) {
        $button.Text = "$server is BUSY ($status users)"
        $button.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Red
    } else {
        $button.Text = "$server is FREE"
        $button.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Green
        $button.Add_Click({ Start-RDP -server $server -credentials $credentials })
    }

    $form.Controls.Add($button)
 }

$form.ShowDialog()

From the script, I was expecting to start a session for the right clicked server.

Change $button.Add_Click({ Start-RDP -server $server -credentials $credentials }) to $button.Add_Click({ Start-RDP -server $server -credentials $credentials }.GetNewClosure())

PowerShell employs dynamic scoping, meaning it defers variable resolution until a variable reference is actually evaluated at runtime - in other words, it doesn't "remember" the value assigned to a local variable reference when you define a scriptblock literal like this:
$server = "abc123"
$scriptblock = { 
  $server
}

$server = "something else now"
& $server # invoking the scriptblock won't return "abc123", but rather "something else now"

In other words, $server is stored as source code in the scriptblock.
By the time either of the button click handler invoke their scriptblock and $server is evaluated, it'll resolve to the last value assigned to $server in the loop.
You can force PowerShell to use lexical scoping by explicitly creating a closure over the local $server variable with ScriptBlock.GetNewClosure():
$button.Add_Click({ Start-RDP -server $server -credentials $credentials }.GetNewClosure())

This will make PowerShell resolve the $server and $credentials variables at the time each script block is defined, storing copies of them in an anonymous module that the resulting closure is then bound to. When you later invoke this closure-style script block (eg. by clicking the associated button), PowerShell will resolve the module-bound copies of $server and $credentials and you get the values you expect.

Note: While closures are entirely appropriate for this kind of infrequently invoked event handler, beware that PowerShell's anonymous-module approach to constructing closures is significantly more expensive than closures in scripting languages for which lexical scoping is the norm (eg. Perl/Python/JavaScript), iow: it's usually slower to invoke than a non-closure.
